# Finding all possible paths in a dataset using sas

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to compare two columns in the dataset shown below

```
Pid       cid
1          2
2          3
2          5
3          6
4          8
8          9
9          4
```

Then produce a result like below

```
1 2 3 6
1 2 5
2 3 6
2 5
3 6
4 8 9 4
8 9 4
9 4
```

First we print the first two values 1 and 2, search for 2 in first column, if its present print its corresponding value from column 2, which is 3. Search for 3 in column 1, if present print the corresponding value from column 2 which is 6

How can this be done using SAS?

Comment: What prevents the infinite cycle `4 8 9 4` ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be 4 8 9 4

Comment: Is the table ordered so that the only possible paths are from top to bottom through the table, or is it possible that you might have to jump back to a row towards the top of the table to find the end of a path?

Your sample table has this property, but it isn't clear whether your full table also has this property.

Comment: E.g. if you added the row `9 1` at the bottom of your sample data, that would mean having to jump back to the top of the table to find the path `9 1 2`. Could rows like that exist?

Comment: Let @ indicate row number  @5 4 -> 8, @6 8 -> 9, @7 9 -> 4, @5 4 -> 8 .. infinite cycle.  In the traversal you want do the @ values always increase ?

Comment: Could optmodel theoretically do this, or would that be Overkill?

Answer (score 1):

The links comprise a directed graph and need recursion to traverse the paths.

In data step, the multiple children of a parent can be stored in a Hash of Hashes structure, but recursion in data step is quite awkward (you would have to manually maintain your own stack and local variables in yet another hash)

In `Proc DS2` recursion is far more traditional and obvious, and `Package Hash` is available.  However, the `Package Hash` hashing is different than data step.  The data values are only allowed to be scalars, so Hash of Hashes is out :(.

The lack of hash of hashes can be remediated by setting up the hash to have `multidata`.  Each data (child) of a key (parent) are retrieved with the pattern `find`, and loop for `has_next`, with `find_next`.

Another issue with hashes in `DS2` is that they must be global to the `data` step, and the same for any host variables used for keys and data.  This makes for tricky management of variables during recursion.  The code at scope depth N can not have any reliance on global variables that can get changed at scope depth N+1.

Fortunately, an anonymous hash can be created in any scope and it's reference is maintained locally... but the key and data variables must still be global; so more careful attention is needed.

The anonymous hash is used to store the multidata retrieved by a key; this is necessary because recursion would affect the `has_next` `get_next` operation.

Sample code.  Requires a rownum variable to prevent cycling that would occur when a child is allowed to act as a parent in a prior row.

```
data have; rownum + 1;input
Pid       cid;datalines;
1          2
2          3
2          5
3          6
4          8
5          12
6          2
8          9
9          4
12         1
12         2
12         14
13         15
14         20
14         21
14         21
15         1
run;

proc delete data=paths;
proc delete data=rows;

%let trace=;

proc ds2 libs=work;
data _null_ ;
  declare double rownum pid cid id step pathid;
  declare int hIndex;

  declare package hash rows();
  declare package hash links();
  declare package hash path();
  declare package hash paths();

  method leaf(int _rootRow, int _step);
    declare double _idLast _idLeaf;

&trace. put ' ';
&trace. put 'LEAF';
&trace. put ' ';
    * no children, at a leaf -- output path;
    rownum = _rootRow;
    if _step < 2 then return;

    * check if same as last one;

    do step = 0 to _step;
      paths.find();  _idLast = id;
      path.find();   _idLeaf = id;
      if _idLast ne _idLeaf then leave;
    end;

    if _idLast = _idLeaf then return;

    pathid + 1;

    do step = 0 to _step;
      path.find();
      paths.add();
    end;
  end;

  method saveStep(int _step, int _id);
&trace. put 'PATH UPDATE' _step ',' _id '               <-------';
    step = _step;
    id = _id;
    path.replace();
  end;

  method descend(int _rootRow, int _fromRow, int _id, int _step);
    declare package hash h;
    declare double _hIndex;
    declare varchar(20) p;

    if _step > 10 then return;

    p = repeat (' ', _step-1);
&trace. put p 'DESCEND:' _rootRow= _fromRow= _id= _step=;

    * given _id as parent, track in path and descend by child(ren);

    * find links to children;
    pid = _id;
&trace. put p 'PARENT KEY:' pid=;
    if links.find() ne 0 then do;
&trace. put p 'NO KEY';
      saveStep(_step, _id);
      leaf(_rootRow, _step);
      return; 
    end;

    * convert multidata to hash, emulating hash of hash;
    * if not, has_next / find_next multidata traversal would be
    * corrupted by a find in the recursive use of descent;

        * new hash reference in local variable;
        h = _new_ hash ([hindex], [cid rownum], 0,'','ascending');

        hIndex = 1;

&trace. put p 'CHILD' hIndex= cid= rownum=;
        if rownum > _fromRow then h.add();

        do while (links.has_next() = 0);
          hIndex + 1;
          links.find_next();

&trace. put p 'CHILD' hIndex= cid= rownum=;
          if rownum > _fromRow then h.add();
        end;

    if h.num_items = 0 then do;
      * no eligble (forward rowed) children links;
&trace. put p 'NO FORWARD CHILDREN';
      leaf(_rootRow, _step-1);
      return;
    end;

    * update data for path step;
    saveStep (_step, _id);

    * traverse hash that was from multidata;
    * locally instantiated hash is protected from meddling outside current scope;
    * hIndex is local variable;
    do _hIndex = 1 to hIndex;
      hIndex = _hIndex;
      h.find();

&trace. put p 'TRAVERSE:' hIndex= cid= rownum= ;

      descend(_rootRow, rownum, cid, _step+1);
    end;

&trace. put p 'TRAVERSE DONE:' _step=;
  end;

  method init(); 
    declare int index;

    * data keyed by rownum;
    rows.keys([rownum]);
    rows.data([rownum pid cid]);
    rows.ordered('A');
    rows.defineDone();

    * multidata keyed by pid;
    links.keys([pid]);
    links.data([cid rownum]);
    links.multidata('yes');
    links.defineDone();

    * recursively discovered ids of path;
    path.keys([step]);
    path.data([step id]);
    path.ordered('A');
    path.defineDone();

    * paths discovered;
    paths.keys([pathid step]);
    paths.data([pathid step id]);
    paths.ordered('A');
    paths.defineDone();
  end;

  method run();
    set have;
    rows.add();
    links.add();
  end;

  method term();
    declare package hiter rowsiter('rows');
    declare int n;

    do while (rowsiter.next() = 0);
      step = 0;
      saveStep (step, pid);
      descend (rownum, rownum, cid, step+1);
    end;

    paths.output('paths');
    rows.output('rows');
  end;
run;
quit;

proc transpose data=paths prefix=ID_ out=paths_across(drop=_name_);
  by pathid;
  id step;
  var id;
  format id_: 4.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments says, infinite cycle and searching path are not clear at least. So let's start with the most simple case: always search from top to bottom and nerve look back.

Just start at create data set:

```
data test;
    input Pid Cid;
    cards;
    1 2
    2 3
    2 5
    3 6
    4 8
    8 9
    9 4
    ;
run;
```

With this assumption, my thought is:

1. Generate a row indicator, E.g. `Ord +1` ;
2. Use a left-join with connection condition `a.Pid = b.Cid and a.Ord > b.Ord` where both a and b stand `test`;
3. Compare the new data set and the old data set;
4. Loop 2 and 3 while new data set differs from the old data set;

Well, sometimes we may care result more than path， so here is another answer:

```
data _null_;
    set test nobs = nobs;

    do i = 1 to nobs;
        set test(rename=(Pid=PidTmp Cid=CidTmp)) point = i;
        if Cid = PidTmp then Cid = CidTmp;
    end;
    put (Pid Cid)(=);
run;
```

Result:

```
Pid=1 Cid=6
Pid=2 Cid=6
Pid=2 Cid=5
Pid=3 Cid=6
Pid=4 Cid=4
Pid=8 Cid=4
Pid=9 Cid=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below, the result is not perfect though

```
data want;
  obs1 = 1; 
  do i=1 to 6;
    set ar ;
    obs2 = obs1 + 1;
    set
      ar(
        rename=(
        pid = pid2 
        cid = cid2
        )
      ) point=obs2
    ;
       if cid =pid2
    then k=catx("",pid,cid,cid2);
    else k=catx("",pid,cid);
    output; 
    obs1 + 1; 

  end; 

run;
```

Result:

```
pid cid k
1   2   1 2 3
2   3   2 3
2   5   2 5
3   6   3 6
4   8   4 8 9
8   9   8 9 4
9   4   9 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation, so this is another answer, hahaha.
First of all, I can see @Richard answer is very good though I can not use ds2 and hash so skillfully yet. It's a nice example to learn recursion.
So now I know your purpose is definitely the path not the end point, store each result while recursing each observation then be necessary. Your own answer has reflecting this but with a failed do-loop, `obs1 = 1` and `obs2 = obs1 + 1` and `obs1 + 1` would always return `obs2 = _N_ + 1` which result in only once loop.
I supplemented and improved the original code this time:

```
data test;
    set test nobs = nobs;

    array Rst[*] Cid Cid1-Cid10;
    do i = _N_ to nobs;
        set test(rename=(Pid=PidTmp Cid=CidTmp)) point = i;
        do j = 1 to dim(Rst);
            if Rst[j] = PidTmp then Rst[j+1] = CidTmp;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

I use an oversize array to store the path and change `do i = 1 to nobs;` to `do i = _N_ to nobs;` since I find `do i = 1 to nobs;` will cause the loop look back.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc ds2;
data _null_;
    declare int t1[7];
    declare int t2[7];
    declare varchar(100) lst;

    method f2(int i, int Y);
        do while (y ^= t1[i] and i < dim(t1));
            i+1;
        end;
        if y = t1[i] then do; 
           lst = cat(lst,t2[i]);
           f2(i, t2[i]);  
        end;
    end;

    method f1(int n, int x, int y);
        dcl int i;
        dcl int match;
        match=0;
        do i = n to dim(t1);
            lst = cat(x,y); 
            if (y = t1[i]) then do;
               f2(i,y);
               put lst=;
               match = 1;
            end;
        end;
        if ^match then put lst=;
    end;

    method init();
    dcl int i;
        t1 := (1 2 2 3 4 8 9);
        t2 := (2 3 5 6 8 9 4);
        do i = 1 to dim(t1);
           f1(i, t1[i], t2[i]);
        end;
    end;
enddata;
run;
quit;`enter code here`
```