# How to find a starting point and destination point of every path in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

How to find a starting point and destination point of every path. Then  below that is a SAS program shows a connection between id field and COPY_FROM_id field, e.g. there are 3 fields, 12 observations, three sets of paths:
[image]
**What I want is shows the below:**
[image]

Do you have any idea on applying SQL of SAS to this question? Thanks!

Comment: This question is a repeat of [Finding all possible paths in a dataset using sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412912/finding-all-possible-paths-in-a-dataset-using-sas/55433521#55433521)

Comment: This is known as a slowly changing dimension if you want to search solutions and approaches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all possible paths in a dataset using sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412912/finding-all-possible-paths-in-a-dataset-using-sas)